# Use dictionary to resolve argument in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and learning Dictionary. I am ended up writing the following program in which I am trying to use dictionary to resolve the argument.

**Program :**

```
def fun1(self)
    options = {'abc': '123', 'edf': '456'}
    args = {'op': options[self.arg]}
```

Now, let's assume that I am passing either `'abc'` or `'edf'` as argument which I am successfully storing in `arg`.

Now, what I want to do here is that I want to fetch value according to the key that passed as argument and want to store that value in `op`

So, is there any problem here in my approach? Are the dictionary tend to use this way? How to achieve this with or without Dictionary?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: It wasn't me, but presumably because you haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: @jpp Not required here. It was a very subtle issue. Look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use mapping dictionaries like this extensively, they are a good way to avoid mutliple if/elif/else statements.

Just be sure to catch missing keys:

```
args = {'op': options.get(self.arg, None)}
```

Or if you don't want to store anything in args:

```
args = {'op': options[self.arg]} if self.arg in options else None
```